# Python - Assign global variable to function return requires function to be global?

Tags: python, function, module, variables, global

So, I'm confused. I have a module containing some function that I use in another module. Imported like so:

```
from <module> import *
```

Inside my module, there exist functions whose purpose is to set global variables in the main program.

main.py:

```
from functions import *

bar = 20
print bar
changeBar()
print bar
```

functions.py:

```
def changeBarHelper(variable):
    variable = variable * 2
    return variable

def changeBar():
    global bar
    bar = changeBarHelper(bar)
```

Now, this is a simplification, but it is the least code that yields the same result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/main.py", line 5, in 
        changeBar()
  File "/path/functions.py", line 7, in changeBar
    bar = changeBarHelper(bar)
NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined
```

Comment: Hint: Don't use global variables.  They're a colossally bad idea.  This is a great of example of why.  They're hard to use.  So don't use them,

Comment: global variables are evil. import * is evil. Evil begets confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing an `import *` in the way that you've done it is a one way process. You've imported a bunch of names, much the same way as you'd do:

```
from mymodule import foo, bar, baz, arr, tee, eff, emm
```

So they are all just assigned to names in the global scope of the module where the `import` is done. What this does not do is connect the global namespaces of these two modules. `global` means **module-global**, not global-to-all-modules. So every module might have its own `fubar` global variable, and assigning to one won't assign to every module.

If you want to access a name from another module, you must import it. So in this example:

```
def foo(var1, var2):
    global bar
    from mainmodule import fubar
    bar = fubar(var1)
```

By doing the import inside the function itself, you can avoid circular imports.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't comment on any of the posts here and this solution isn't working. I would like to clarify this a bit.

There are two modules here:

main.py:

```
from functions import *

bar = 20
print bar
changeBar()
print bar
```

functions.py:

```
def changeBarHelper(variable):
    variable = variable * 2
    return variable

def changeBar():
    global bar
    bar = changeBarHelper(bar)
```

Now, this is a simplification, but it is the least code that yields the same result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/main.py", line 5, in 
    changeBar()
  File "/path/functions.py", line 7, in changeBar
    bar = changeBarHelper(bar)
NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined
```

Now, the solution given isn't working for me, and this is a problem I would really like a solution to.

Answer (score 0):

def changeBar()

needs to be:

def changeBar(bar)

that way when you call changeBar(bar) in main.py

functions.py works on bar variable from main.py

sooo...

```
from functions import *

bar = 20
print bar
bar = changeBar(bar)
print bar

def changeBarHelper(variable):
    variable = variable * 2
    return variable

def changeBar(bar):
    bar = changeBarHelper(bar)
    return bar
```